# Displaying results in table of data in a ListBox from TextBoxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am doing an assignment on the population of organisms where there are three TextBoxes in my application, that would get the user's input on the "Starting number of organisms" (StartingNumOfOrganismsTextBox), "Average daily increase" (DailyIncreaseTextBox), and "Days to multiply" (NumOfDaysTextBox).

```
        int NumOfOrganisms = 0, DailyIncrease = 0, NumOfDays = 1;

        StartingNumOfOrganisms = int.Parse(StartingNumOfOrganismsTextBox.Text);
        DailyIncrease = int.Parse(DailyIncreaseTextBox.Text);
        NumOfDays = int.Parse(NumOfDaysTextBox.Text);
```

When the user inputs int numbers in those textboxes, there should be a Calculate Button, when pressed, it should automatically display the users inputs into a separate ListBox named (PopulationsListBox), as a table of data like this:

For example, if a user enters the following inputs in the TextBoxes mentioned:
StartingNumOfOrganismsTextBox: 2 DailyIncreaseTextBox:  30% NumOfDaysTextBox:      5

Pressing the calculate button, the application should display the following table of data in a ListBox control in two columns. (Day) column, and (Approximate Population) column.

Day 1, Approximate Population 2. Day 2, Approximate Population 2.6. Day 3, Approximate Population 3.38. Day 4 Approximate Population 4.394. Day 5, Approximate Population 5.7122.

Will someone give me hints on how to take all three of the user inputs, (StartingNumOfOrgranisms, DailyIncrease[%] and then the NumOfDays the organisms will be left to multiply, and display the data of table ina  ListBox control? This is very confusing for me, I will be extremely grateful if anyone could help me with this assignment. Thanks.

Also, I have tried to use the ListView code format to add my data:

```
        PopulationsListBox.Items.Add("1");
        PopulationsListBox.Items[0].SubItems.Add(StartingNumOfOrganisms.ToString());
        for (int i=2;i<=NumOfDays;++i)
        {
           PopulationsListBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
           PopulationsListBox.Items[PopulationsListBox.Items.Count-1].SubItems.Add((StartingNumOfOrganisms+StartingNumOfOrganisms*DailyIncrease).ToString());
```

But, "SubItems" is not a property ListBoxes use. Perhaps someone could suggest trying something similar to that for me? I will be thankful.

Comment: If each element consists of multiple data, are you sure you want a `ListBox` and not a `ListView`?

Comment: According to the rules, I cannot use a ListView to put my table of data in. It has to be a ListBox. :( I did try to use it at ListView format, but sadly, when I add data as a "SubItem" apparently ListBoxes do not have a SubItem Property.

Comment: "According to the rules" - are we helping you with your home work?

Comment: @LostManos, Sorry if that offended you, I did not mean to. What I meant was, according to my project goals I cannot use ListViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but you want to do something like this:

```
        listbox.Items.Add("Day 1, Approximate Population:" + txtStartingNumberOfOrganisms.Text);
        int ApproximatePopulation = Convert.ToInt16(txtStartingNumberOfOrganisms.Text);             

        for (int i = 2; i <= numOfDays; i++)
        {
            ApproximatePopulation = ApproximatePopulation + ((ApproximatePopulation * Convert.ToDouble(txtDailyIncrease.text)) / 100);
            listbox.Items.Add("Day " + Convert.ToString(i) + ", Approximate Population:" + Convert.ToString(ApproximatePopulation));
        }
```

Apologies if the sums are all over the place but you can figure those out ;)

Comment: Made a couple of edits because I didn't convert the textbox data

Comment: Thank you Steven. :) I have figured my project out using your code.